# ODAC for .NET is slow

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 instance and Oracle 10g database installed side by side on the same remote server with the same exact data loaded in each.

I've written a program to time a simple query which return about 10,000 records (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE X=X).  What I'm seeing through this test is Oracle returns anywhere from 4-12 times slower than MSSQL.  I've tested on a LAN connection, remotely through VPN, using ODP.NET4, ODP.NET2, ensuring the proper 32 bit version is installed on a 32 bit operating system, and the same for 64 bit.

My results are always the same in that Oracle is always many times slower than the SQL Server instance.

I've also tried the same query inside SQL Developer, and this tool retrieves the same recordset much faster.  When I force the tool to retrieve all records it comes through about 20% slower than SQL Server, which would at least be acceptable in my scenario.

Any help is appreciate.  I know there are several similar questions but the answers from these have not helped resolve the problem.

Thanks

- From database server: 3s (Oracle) vs 0.6s (SQL Server)
- From somewhere in lan: 22s (Oracle) vs 4s (SQL Server)
- From remote machine through vpn: 54s (Oracle) vs 21s (SQL Developer) vs 13s (SQL Server)

**Additional question: Is this the performance hit that you experience in your ODP.NET + SQL Server compliant applications, or am I right to assume that something is wrong?**

Comment: Are you measuring the speed based on the time it takes to START returning records, or the time it takes to FINISH returning all 10,000 records?

Comment: The time it takes to return all records and fill in a datatable (using a DataAdapter)

Comment: Microsoft Product -> Microsoft Product = fast; Microsoft Product -> Other Product = slow. Of course there would be optimizations in products that share a vendor. Just FYI, I've seen exactly what you're experiencing multiple times in production.

Comment: Do you need a DataTable?  Try DataReader into a collection (E.G. List).

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be a DataTable which is another problem entirely.  There's just too much code relying on it to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you [setting a fetch size](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-jul/o46odp-097508.html) in your application?  If so, have you tried setting different fetch sizes and measuring how that affects the elapsed time?  I believe SQL Developer defaults to a fetch size of 500 (though I don't by any stretch guarantee that) so you might use that as a starting point.

Comment: Justin, thank you this really helped.  Do you know if there are any downsides in defaulting to a very large fetch size?  Adjusting the value to 600,000 improved performance up to only 2x slower than SQL Server which is certainly better than the 15x I was experiencing.

Comment: @user112799 - Depending on the network, I would tend to expect at least some decline when the fetch size grew too large.  And there should be a pretty rapidly declining benefit as the fetch size grows-- in the white paper that I linked to, for example, going from a fetch size of 1 to a fetch size of 10 produced an ~80% reduction in elapsed time while going from a fetch size of 1000 to 10000 only produced a ~5% reduction.  A fetch size of 600,000 is pretty large but if that's what you found is optimal in your app, it's not completely outside the realm of reasonableness.